# Time delay of 15 seconds before page reload called from javascript with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

At the expiry of a timer in javascript, I request that the page be reloaded to refresh the status of a number of NodeMCU'in iframes.   The code works perfectly in Safari on the Ipad and Microsoft edge.  However, it will not work correctly with Chrome in that there is a significant delay of about 15 seconds or so before the page refreshes. I monitored the network with Wireshark, and the page reload request is delayed going out on the network.

And note it has this behaviour on two different PC's, so it has something to do compatibility with Chrome.  I tried changing all kinds of setting parameters in Chrome to no avail.  I tried a wide range of commands to refresh the page --- all worked properly with Safari and Edge --- same delay issue with Chrome.  I also experimented with calling another function on "onTimesUP" to handle the page refresh, and it didn't work with Chrome either.

Here is a snippet of the code from the timer that calls for the page update.

```
function onTimesUp() {
clearInterval(timerInterval);
window.location.href = "http://192.168.0.188";
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You're probably fighting the browsers internal defense against page hijacking, Chrome tries to reasonably open pages when a user expects it, if there's no click, or user input, it's very likely it's actually blocking your code. I'm not sure what the name of this is though.  Your question feels a lot like [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
function windowFunction(){
    window.location.href = "http://192.168.0.188";
}

var myVar;
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(winodwFunction, 15000);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Greetings, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just a heads up-- I think you may have misunderstood the intent of the question.  The question isn't asking _how_ to apply a 15 second timeout before reloading the page; it is asking _why_ a 15 second delay exists on certain browsers when trying to reload the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and comments.  Indeed the issue is why won’t chrome handle the reload request immediately.  It just clocks for about 15 seconds before the page reloads.  If Chrome thinks it is a security issue, why does it eventually reload and what is it doing to validate the request.  I will take a look at the xy problem John referred to.

Comment: I did extensive testing of the code, and it does not appear to be the timer code, but rather the call to set the pins on the all of the NodeMCU’s to zero that is causing excessive delay.  Still digging her to understand this.